# How to set a global property in a Rails app for the layout with a default value that can be overridden in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to have a single layout.html.erb with a few variables that can be overridden in the controller such as bootstrap's "container" and "container-fluid".

I was thinking of having a helper like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def which_layout
    @layout || "container"
  end
```

in controller:

```
  def holding
    @layout="container-fluid"
  end
```

and in layout:

```
<div class='<%=which_layout %>'>
```

but this is not working. Also, doing it in application_controller doesn't work. Such as:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  @layout="container"
```

What would be an effective way to achieve this in as centralized place as possible? I might want to query in a helper which controller / method combo and output the appropriate layout value too.

### Edit

So doing something like this in application.html.erb works:

```
  <div class='<%=@layout || "container" %>'>
```

and then just in a controller

```
  def holding
    @layout="container-fluid"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just only create a method on your ApplicationController that return the default layout, or instead, use a hook in order to call `layout :name`

Comment: both application_helper and application_controller are pretty useless in this case. I definitely don't want to create a second layout. Another solution would just be something in global config but I don't really like that as I feel this is more of an application level concern. A writable applicaton_controller method would be ideal but, surpisingly, doesn't work.  I think hte edit might be the best but I'm still not very happy with as I feel this should either be in application_helper or application_controller.